# as3 breakpoints not triggering in child swf

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging

I've a preloader which is instantiating a child swf.  The breakpoints work in the preloader swf, but not in the child that it is loading.  The child is loaded in to the same application domain and debug is on for both.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by changing my swf loading mechanism switching to using LoadBytes fixed it!